# AngularJs DatePicker not showing view

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, datepicker

I am new to AngularJS and trying to integrate the Angular Material Date Picker with AngularJS but I can't see the calendar(controller/date.controller.js, 
 views/calendar.html).Please find the link of plunkr(whole app) and let me know your suggestions.

http://plnkr.co/edit/cHXi8EBfrhcTfwBvJ5nU?p=preview
Below is the controller

```
 'use strict';
angular.module('plunkr', ['ngMaterial' , 'ngMessages']).controller('mycont', function(){
      this.myDate = new Date();
      this.isOpen = false;

    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You have some issues in your code thats why calendar doesnt show.

First of all, you have two app module one named  **plunkr** and other named **plunker** thats cause some injector fail, also in each controller you redefine entire module adding the `[]` part.

**main.controllers.js**

```
angular.module('plunker', []).controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {....
```

**date.controller.js**

```
angular.module('plunkr', ['ngMaterial' , 'ngMessages']).controller('mycont', function(){....
```

**app.js**

```
angular.module('plunker', []);
```

here is the fork [plknr](http://embed.plnkr.co/MajMO5q906qilCjHVSYj/) i took from yours.